# Another query on higher order differentials of a single variable function

Tags: calculus

Given a function $y = f(x)$ which is continuous and differentiable on its domain, the differential of the function, $dy = d(f(x))$ is defined by, $$dy = d(f(x)) = f'(x)\Delta x$$

In words, the differential of a single variable function of $x$ at $x$ is defined as its derivative at $x$ multiplied by $\Delta x$. 
According to most books, the second order differential of the same function is, $$ d^2y = d^2(f(x)) = d(df(x)) = f''(x)(\Delta x)^2$$ However, i simply dont understand how this definition came about.

The way I did it was that I treated the first order differential of $f(x)$ as another function of $x$, say $d(f(x)) = h(x)$ and that taking the second order differential of $f(x)$ is equivalent to taking the differential of the new function $h(x)$ so,  $$d^2y = d(d(fx)) = d(h(x)) $$
where, $h(x) = f'(x) \Delta x$. Hence,  $$d(h(x)) = h'(x)\Delta x = f''(x)\Delta x^2$$
Am I doing this correctly? I am not sure if thats correct at all. Thanks guys.

Comment: I don't see your question. Didn't you just find the same result?

Comment: By the way, the second differential should be *bilinear*. i.e. $d^2y=f''(x)(\Delta x)_1 (\Delta x)_2$.

Comment: Just a hunch but im asking whether its correct